# Can anyone help me with the following JScript?

Tags: javascript, windows-vista, special-folders

In Vista, I am trying to get "Local AppData" path for an user account (other than current user) on a local machine but facing some issue. can anyone pls help me what is wrong with the below code.

```
var HKU = 0x80000003; 
var username = "xyz";

//Loading registry hive of user xyz
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var LoadHiveCmd = "REG LOAD " + "HKU" + "\\" + username + " \"" + "c:\\users\\xyz\\NTUSER.DAT" + "\"";
var oExec = WshShell.Exec(strLoadHiveCmd); 

var oReg = GetObject("WinMgmts:/root/default:StdRegProv"); 

var profileRegPath = username  + "\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\User Shell Folders";

var method, inparams, outparams;  

method = oReg.Methods_.Item("GetExpandedStringValue");
inparams = method.InParameters.SpawnInstance_();
inparams.hDefKey = HKU;
inparams.sSubKeyName = profileRegPath ;
inparams.sValueName =  "Local AppData";

outparams = oReg.ExecMethod_(method.Name, inparams);
var appDataPath= outparams.sValue;
```

Here the appDataPath value in the registry is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`

But I am getting a value `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local`

I dont understand from where the value `c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile` is coming and how it replaced `%USERPROFILE%` value.

Comment: A Community user was nice enough to format your code for you. Please Have a look at [How to format code on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in order to assure you providing the code in an easy-to-read format for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

USERPROFILE is a environment variable and will replace %USERPROFILE% to get it's correct location on this computer. it changes from computer to computer.

To see all environment variables type "set" on a command shell, or go to "Control Panel" > "System settings" > "Advanced" > Environment variables

Comment: The %USERPROFILE% environment value is not the one c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile. When I checked, the value of userprofile for the current process is c:\users\admin. Couldn't understand where from this systemprofile string came

Comment: When you open the registry editor, what branch you browse to? You have to go to HKEY_USERS\[xyz user id]\Software\...

Comment: ya.. i am going to HKU_USERS\Xyz branch only. But I am loading hive of xyz  thru reg load and my current process is running with admin user. That is why the value of %userprofile% is c:\users\admin but not c:\users\stduser

Comment: yes, USERPROFILE would only get the correct value if you log in using the user account.

Answer (score 0):

`GetExpandedStringValue` automatically replaces any environment variables included in the registry value data with actual values of these variables. Most likely, %USERPROFILE% expands to *C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile* instead of *C:\users\admin* because the WMI service itself runs under Local System account.

What you need to get your script working is to:

- use `GetStringValue` instead of `GetExpandedStringValue` to read the unexpanded `Local AppData` value,
- get the profile path of the needed user by reading the `ProfileImagePath` value from the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<user_SID>` key,
- do a string replace to substitute %USERPROFILE% with the profile path.

You can find an example of how to do this in this my answer:
[Getting special Folder path for a given user in Jscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571747/getting-special-folder-path-for-a-given-user-in-jscript/5572522#5572522)

You may also want to use [`WshShell.RegRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd.aspx) instead of WMI, because it's more JScript-friendly.

Comment: Unfortunately, GetStringValue behaves exactly like GetExpandedStringValue when used on a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (I'm not sure what the difference is, actually)